# WhatsApp link preview

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags, meta, whatsapp

I am using OG Meta tag to Facebook Photo Post 1200px x 630px and its nice. But now WhatsApp link preview is awesome but the thumb is a square like 60px 60px or something like that.

When I share link from WhatsApp it get my OG image and show but its a rectangle and its not fit.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBlSQ.png)

How can I specify OG meta tag or some meta tag to WhatsApp and keep Facebook meta tag?

Wich size image is WhatsApp thumb from link preview?

Thanks

Comment: you should try to set the right og meta image property via some media query css rules

Comment: @CiroCorvino Did you do it before or its just a suggestion?

Comment: just suggestion :) ... otherwise I should have answered

Comment: I have the same issue, like if i am using 1.91:1 image then facebook is fine but whatsapp is showing cropped image.